# enter cash payed after i`m done choosing my order

Tags: vb.net, forms, listbox

Im using visual basic language on visual studio 2010.I want to be asked to enter the cash payed after im done picking the order, now it asks to enter cash after every item i choose.

below you'll find the code and screenshots

```
Dim choice As String
Dim price As Double
Dim quantity As Integer
Dim total As Double
Dim tpayable As Double
Dim cash As Double
Dim change As Double
Dim spaces As String = Space(4)
Private Sub menue_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim spaces As String = Space(4)


End Sub


Private Sub badd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles badd.Click
    quantity = InputBox("enter item quantity", "quantity")

    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        choice = "Potato soup"
        price = "80"
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
        choice = "Salmon roll"
        price = "100"
    ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked Then
        choice = "Smoked salmon potatos"
        price = "75"
    End If
    If RadioButton4.Checked Then
        choice = "Lasagna"
        price = "250"
    ElseIf RadioButton5.Checked Then
        choice = "Cheese burger"
        price = "120"
    ElseIf RadioButton6.Checked Then
        choice = "Pizza"
        price = "450"

    ElseIf RadioButton7.Checked Then
        choice = "ugali & sukuma"
        price = "80"
    ElseIf RadioButton8.Checked Then
        choice = "Chicken fried noodles"
        price = "150"
    End If
    If RadioButton9.Checked Then
        choice = "Chocolate fudge cake"
        price = "250"
    ElseIf RadioButton10.Checked Then
        choice = "Ice cream"
        price = "150"
    ElseIf RadioButton11.Checked Then
        choice = "Carrot Cake"
        price = "230"
    End If
    If RadioButton12.Checked Then
        choice = "Black tea"
        price = "80"
    ElseIf RadioButton13.Checked Then
        choice = "White tea"
        price = "80"
    ElseIf RadioButton14.Checked Then
        choice = "Coffee"
        price = "80"
    End If
    If RadioButton15.Checked Then
        choice = "Coke"
        price = "60"

    ElseIf RadioButton16.Checked Then
        choice = "Milkshake"
        price = "110"

    ElseIf RadioButton17.Checked Then
        choice = "Fanta"
        price = "60"
    End If


    total = quantity * price
    tpayable += total

    txttpayable.Text = Str(tpayable)

    cash = InputBox("enter cash payed")

    txtcgiven.Text = Str(cash)

    change = cash - tpayable

    txtchange.Text = Str(change)





    ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Concat(choice & spaces & price & spaces & quantity & spaces & total & spaces & tpayable))

End Sub
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLV3x.jpg)

Comment: Please keep each thread to a single question. If you have four issues then create four threads and then you can separately accept an answer for each one.  That's how this site works.  It also means that you can keep the code you post to only what's relevant to that one specific question.  Can you edit your post to remove all but the first question and post each of the others separately?

Comment: @jmcilhinney alright

Comment: @jmcilhinney now could you please try answering my question?

Comment: I think that the issue is most likely that you have `` inside that `For Each` loop. It seems more logical that you would display the form after adding all the items to the `ListBox`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I don`t understand. My question has to do with the cash part.

Comment: Then why is that other part even there? Notice how I said earlier that posting just one question allows you to post only the code that is relevant to that question?  If you post irrelevant code then you distract from the actual problem and end up wasting everyone's time, as has happened here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney there i removed the irrelevant code.

Comment: You need to handle an appropriate event. At the moment, you're handling the `Click` event of `badd` and prompting then. What event is raised when you want the prompt to occur? Is there another `Button` that the user clicks when they selected all the items? If so, move the code that prompts for the amount there. If not, how do you know that all the items have been selected?

Comment: @jmcilhinney the prompt occurs after i select an item. but i want the prompt to occcur when im  done selecting multiple items.there are no other buttons associated with the items(radiobuttons). The problem is that I want the prompt to occur after im done selecting all the items i want.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have a better idea. why dont i just add a seperate textbox asking for the amount next to each radiobutton, then i prompt the cash payed after im done choosing the amount for multiple items. will that work instead?

Answer (score 0):

The application can't read your mind. It can only react to some input from you. You need to handle an appropriate event to let the application know that you have made all the appropriate selections and so it needs to prompt. Looking more closely at your code, it appears that you have several groups of `RadioButtons`. Assuming that the user must select one option from each group, you can handle the `CheckedChanged` event of all the `RadioButtons` and then check whether one is checked from each group.  Here's a simplified example using two groups of two that you can extend to any number of groups and controls:

```
Private Sub RadioButtons_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged,
                                                                                  RadioButton2.CheckedChanged,
                                                                                  RadioButton3.CheckedChanged,
                                                                                  RadioButton4.CheckedChanged
    If Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().Any(Function(rb) rb.Checked) AndAlso
       Panel2.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().Any(Function(rb) rb.Checked) Then
        'A selection has been made from each group.
    End If           
End Sub
```

This assumes that `RadioButton1` and `RadioButton2` are on `Panel1` and `RadioButton2` and `RadioButton3` are on `Panel2`. As I said, there can be as many groups as you like and each group can contain as many options as you like. Each group can be on a `Panel`, a `GroupBox` or some other container.

Comment: What is rb in the brackets?

Comment: "They are GroupBoxes..."  Did I not address that specifically?  You use the `Controls` property of the `Panel`, `GroupBox` or some other container.

Comment: The arguments to the `Any` calls are Lambda expressions. You should do some research on that. `rb` is the parameter of that anonymous method and it is type `RadioButton`. Basically that code says "in the list items of type `RadioButton` in the `Controls` collection of `Panel1`, are there any that have the value `True` for their `Checked` property. The Lambda expression is an anonymous method that takes a `RadioButton` and returns the value of its `Checked` property.

Comment: i decided to use radio buttons instead. Is the code gonna remain the same. ps sorry im new to vb and this site.

Comment: `RadioButtons` instead... of what? Everything I've posted so far is predicated on the fact that you're using `RadioButtons`. Did you even read my code? Did you not see how many times `RadioButton` appears in it?

Comment: If each group of `CheckBoxes` is in a separate container, e.g. `Panel` or `GroupBox`, and you require the user to check at least one box in each group then the code pattern would not change. As the name suggests, the `Any` method will return `True` if any items in the list it is called on satisfy the specified condition. "Any" means one or more. Of course, you could have tested for yourself to see.